# Alternatives to the XAML Live Preview in Visual Studio for Mac 2022

Tags: xcode, xaml, maui, visual-studio-mac

Prior to me transitioning my work in MacBook, I'm used to using the XAML Live Preview tool of Visual Studio 2022 in my Windows Laptop. However, I noticed that this is not the case for Visual Studio 2022 for Mac as this feature is not included.

I'm looking for alternatives for this tool. I currently have my Xcode and iOS Simulator. But I don't know how to use it to inspect the elements.

Any alternatives which you can suggest?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?tabs=vswin

Comment: Unfortunately, there is currently no alternative to XAML Live Preview.